# How to encode latin characters with urllib3 request_encode_url?

Tags: python, python-3.x, url-encoding, urllib3

i have a function to download a website html code with the urllib3 library. I'm using the request_encode_url function to pass arguments by GET and it works fine if i do not use special latin characters like 'ñ'. If i use 'ñ', the url is not properly encoded.

For instance, if i pass an argument like "El señor" this function converts it to "El+seÃ±or" instead of "El+se%F1or".

```
z='El señor'
fields={'sec':'search','value': z}
http = urllib3.PoolManager() 
r = http.request_encode_url('GET', 'http://www.myurl.com/search.php',fields)
```

The expected url must be like:

```
http://www.myurl.com/search.php?sec=search&value=El+se%F1or
```

but if i use special characters i obtain next url:

```
http://www.myurl.com/search.php?sec=search&value=El+seÃ±or
```

Somebody can say me how can i pass arguments with special characters to encode a correct url?

I'm using Python 3.4

Comment: If I run your code, I actually get `'http://www.myurl.com/search.php?sec=search&value=El+se%C3%B1or'` as requested URL. Could it be an encoding problem with your source file?

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution, maybe it's a silly thing but i have a low level in python.

I solve it encoding string into latin1:

```
z='El señor'
fields={'sec':'search','value': z.encode('latin1')}
http = urllib3.PoolManager() 
r = http.request_encode_url('GET', 'http://www.myurl.com/search.php',fields)
```